# Using joined column with orderBy clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a distinct error "ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" which is happening because my select distinct doesn't have the column which I'm trying to order by (`d.name`), it has been joined from another table:

```
select distinct r.id,
                r.name
from record r
        inner join dict d on r.status_id = d.id
order by d.name desc
```

Most obvious solution would be to add `d.code` into the select, but I don't seem to be able easily find the solution which allows to do so with rsql query parser,

```
public Specification<T> parseQuery(String searchQuery, boolean distinct, ZoneId timeZone) {
        if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchQuery)) {
            return null;
        }
        Node rootNode = new RSQLParser(operators).parse(searchQuery);
        final Specification<T> accept = rootNode.accept(new CustomRsqlVisitor<>(timeZone));
        if (!distinct || accept == null) {
            return accept;
        } else {
            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                Predicate predicate = accept.toPredicate(root, query, criteriaBuilder);
                query.distinct(true);
                return predicate;
            };
        }
    }
```

Because its seems to be generified with a repository that is working with it, and original select only uses enitity that has been passed into it.

Is there any simple workarounds that I can use to make error go away? (except for disabling distinct altogether)?

Or ditching the whole specification thing, is there a specific postgres query that I should run to avoid this error instead of putting the orderBy field into select?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want  the `name` from `r`:

```
select distinct r.id, r.name
from record r join
     dict d
     on r.status_id = d.id
order by r.name desc;
```

EDIT:

Careful inspection of the question suggests that you really want `d.code`.  If you really do want an unselected column from `d`, then you can use `group by`:

```
select r.id, r.name
from record r join
     dict d
     on r.status_id = d.id
group by r.id, r.name
order by max(d.code) desc;
```

Note the use of an aggregation function in the `order by`.

Comment: My bad, I've renamed orderBy part, but forgot to rename it in the text below. It is d.name or course

Comment: I want to orderBy the column name of a joined dict d